# Rails 3: Fastest way to determine model popularity by counting association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a Post model which has_many Comments.  I want to get the top 10 most popular posts based on those who have the most comments. Assuming I have hundreds of thousands of posts, what's the most efficient way of getting those 10 top posts?

Also, how do I cache that query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you add a counter-cache column on `Post` called `comments_count`. Add an index on this column, and then you can select the most popular posts by:

```
# app/models/post.rb
scope :popular, lambda { order("comments_count DESC").limit(10) }
```

Check out the [ActiveRecord associations class methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) document for more info on counter-caches.

Comment: Wonderful suggestion, Jeriko.  Thank you!